# Databricks keeps showing "Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80" error when trying to run shell command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, databricks

I am following the instructions from this recent [post](https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D58Y00009SWgVuSAL) in an AWS backed Databricks platform to get Selenium to work and can't get past this error every time I run the below code:

Partial Error:

```
Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80
```

Code:

```
%sh
/dbfs/databricks/scripts/selenium-install.sh
```

I have provided the full error at the bottom of this post. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? I looked at the Network ACLs and Security Groups defaulted in the AWS account and it looks like I should have access to in/outbound HTTP(80) ports, but I am not an AWS expert. I added a new Security Group for Outbout 80 access to try and troubleshoot but didn't work and is probably redundent. Could use some help troubleshooting.

I tried running the below as the full error suggested and get am getting simular error messages:

Suggested Code:

```
%sh
sudo apt-get update
```

Full Error:

```
/dbfs/databricks/scripts/selenium-install.sh: line 3: fg: no job control

                                                                           0.0%
                                                                           0.5%
####                                                                       5.6%
#######                                                                   11.0%
###########                                                               16.4%
###############                                                           21.8%
###################                                                       27.3%
#######################                                                   32.8%
###########################                                               38.2%
###############################                                           43.7%
###################################                                       49.1%
#######################################                                   54.5%
###########################################                               60.0%
###############################################                           65.5%
###################################################                       70.9%
######################################################                    76.4%
##########################################################                81.8%
##############################################################            87.3%
##################################################################        92.7%
######################################################################    98.2%
######################################################################## 100.0%
Archive:  /tmp/chrome/1075160-chrome-linux.zip
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/MEIPreload/manifest.json  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/MEIPreload/preloaded_data.pb  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/chrome  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/chrome-wrapper  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/chrome_100_percent.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/chrome_200_percent.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/chrome_crashpad_handler  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/chrome_sandbox  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/icudtl.dat  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/libEGL.so  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/libGLESv2.so  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/libvk_swiftshader.so  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/libvulkan.so.1  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/nacl_helper  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/nacl_helper_bootstrap  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe  
 extracting: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/product_logo_48.png  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/resources.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/v8_context_snapshot.bin  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/vk_swiftshader_icd.json  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/xdg-mime  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/xdg-settings  
   creating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/ClearKeyCdm/
   creating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/ClearKeyCdm/_platform_specific/
   creating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/ClearKeyCdm/_platform_specific/linux_x64/
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/ClearKeyCdm/_platform_specific/linux_x64/libclearkeycdm.so  
   creating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/de.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/bg.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ko.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/he.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sr.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/hr.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/af.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ar.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ro.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sv.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ar.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/vi.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/es-419.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/nl.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ro.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/es-419.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/it.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ru.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/pt-BR.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/fr.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/th.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ko.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sk.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/es.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/nb.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/kn.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/fa.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/de.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/el.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/hu.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/it.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/lv.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/bg.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/zh-TW.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/zh-CN.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/zh-CN.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/cs.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/el.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ms.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/en-GB.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ar-XB.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sl.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/kn.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/tr.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ur.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/uk.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/cs.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/da.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ru.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/fi.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/fil.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/pt-PT.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/pl.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/es.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/hi.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/nl.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/te.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/bn.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/he.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/en-GB.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/en-US.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/af.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ta.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sk.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/uk.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/gu.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/gu.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ca.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/am.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/mr.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ja.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sl.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/fa.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/en-US.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ta.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/id.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ml.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/hr.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/en-XA.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/pl.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/en-XA.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/bn.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/am.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/pt-BR.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sv.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/lv.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/zh-TW.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ja.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ur.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/pt-PT.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ms.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/th.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/et.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/lt.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ca.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/tr.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sw.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sr.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/fr.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/lt.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/hu.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/da.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/fil.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ml.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/et.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/ar-XB.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/id.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/te.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/vi.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/nb.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/hi.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/fi.pak.info  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/sw.pak  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/locales/mr.pak.info  
   creating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/resources/
   creating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/resources/inspector_overlay/
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/resources/inspector_overlay/main.js  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chrome-linux/resources/inspector_overlay/inspector_overlay_resources.grd  

#                                                                          1.7%
#############################################################             84.8%
######################################################################## 100.0%
Archive:  /tmp/chrome/1075160-chromedriver_linux64.zip
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chromedriver_linux64/LICENSE.chromedriver  
  inflating: /tmp/chrome/1075160/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver  
Hit:1 https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb stable InRelease
Err:2 http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable InRelease
  Could not connect to repos.azulsystems.com:80 (18.67.66.46), connection timed out Could not connect to repos.azulsystems.com:80 (18.67.66.48), connection timed out Could not connect to repos.azulsystems.com:80 (18.67.66.69), connection timed out Could not connect to repos.azulsystems.com:80 (18.67.66.82), connection timed out
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to repos.azulsystems.com:80 (18.67.66.46), connection timed out Could not connect to repos.azulsystems.com:80 (18.67.66.48), connection timed out Could not connect to repos.azulsystems.com:80 (18.67.66.69), connection timed out Could not connect to repos.azulsystems.com:80 (18.67.66.82), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcap2-bin libpam-cap zulu-8 zulu-repo
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgbm1 libwayland-server0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgbm-dev libgbm1 libwayland-server0
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 66.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 355 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libwayland-server0 amd64 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.4
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libgbm1 amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libgbm-dev amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libwayland-server0 amd64 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.4
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wayland/libwayland-server0_1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.4_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm1_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm-dev_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is associated with outbound access controls in our firewall system that manages users and controls network settings to our AWS platform services. Was only allowing access to port 443 (HTTPS) and MySQL. Needed to add port 80 in order to allow for these commands to run over HTTP.